# How does 'git pull <remote> <branchname>' work?

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm a bit confused by this part of the [`git-pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) documentation:

> ```
> $ git pull origin next
> ```
>
> This leaves a copy of `next` temporarily in `FETCH_HEAD`, but does not
>   update any remote-tracking branches.

Does this form of `git pull` actually get new commits from the remote repository into the local one?

Comment: It does (and `origin/next` remote now points to the tip of remote branch), just your local branches need to be merged/rebased in order to show new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The very short answer is yes: `git fetch` obtains their commits and puts them into your repository.  But the `git pull` documentation is wrong here, in a small but significant way.

#### Long

I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`, at least until you are pretty familiar with the internal workings of the two commands it runs.  Instead, use two separate commands: `git fetch`, then—assuming you intend to merge—`git merge`.  However, this does deserve some explanation.  In particular, the claim that this

> does not update any remote-tracking branches

is generally wrong, although in some specific cases it can be correct.  It *was* correct for Git versions predating Git 1.8.2.

As documented, `git pull` runs `git fetch` and then a second Git command, usually `git merge`.  The first (fetch) command gets most of the options and arguments that you pass to `git pull`, although a few options get taken away and passed instead to `git merge` or `git rebase`, or even used directly by `git pull` itself.

In the specific case of:

```
git pull origin next
```

this runs:

```
git fetch origin next
```

which directs `git fetch` to:

- call up the other Git at the result of `git config --get remote.origin.url`;
- when that Git lists all its branches and tags, only fetch from its `next` (branch or tag, usually branch); and
- suppress updating of *most* remote-tracking names (Git tends to call these *remote-tracking branch names* but since they're not branches in one important sense, I like to use the shorter phrase, *remote-tracking names*).

The documentation here is referring to the last of these three items.  However, ever since Git version 1.8.2, Git now performs what the Git documentation calls "opportunistic updates": if Git has brought over `origin`'s `next`, Git updates your own `origin/next`, *even when it doesn't update any other remote-tracking names*.<sup>1</sup>  In all cases, `git fetch` writes into `.git/FETCH_HEAD` the hash ID and names of the branch(es) or tag(s) it brought in.

The subsequent `git merge` that `git pull` runs uses the hash ID from this `FETCH_HEAD` file, along with the message that's on the line(s) that are *not* marked `not-for-merge`.  See the section below about the contents of the `FETCH_HEAD` file.

---

<sup>1</sup>The mechanism for this kind of opportunistic update is particularly tortuous: Git reads the value of `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` to find out how to rename the branch names on the *other* Git when translating them into remote-tracking names in *your* Git repository.  If you set this to something other than its normal default, or if there is no setting, the documentation's claim may become correct even in Git versions 1.8.2 or later.

If you use a URL instead of a remote name, of course, there's no way for Git to know what names to update opportunistically.  So in *this* case—when you run:

```
git fetch https://example.com/repo.git
```

for instance—there are no remote-tracking names to update, regardless of whether you add additional refspecs to the command.

---

#### Commit hash IDs, or what `git fetch` brings over

The really important part of `git fetch` is that it brings over *commits*.  Specifically, it brings over commits whose hash IDs *their* Git has in their repository, that *your* Git does not have in *your* repository.  Git uses some graph theory to figure out what commits, and what other objects, need to be brought from their repository to yours, based on which name(s) you told `git fetch` to fetch.  The normal default is *all branch names and some tag names*.

These objects—mostly commits and the files that go with them—are all identified by these hash IDs.  It's the hash IDs that Git is concerned with here.  You either have something that has the hash ID, or you don't; if you don't, `git fetch` brings it over.

Once you have the objects, your Git retains them as long as *something* has a *name* for the object, or the object is *reachable from* something that has a name.  The process for doing this is analogous to garbage collection in many modern languages such as Java, Python, and Go (and much older languages such as Lisp and most of its descendants too).  Essentially, given some set of starting points, Git walks through the graph formed by reading the commits<sup>2</sup> to get their parent hash IDs.  Any commits or other objects reached during this graph-walk are *referenced* and remain; any commits or other objects *not* reached are unreferenced and are eligible for deletion.

The contents of the `FETCH_HEAD` file count here: any hash IDs on the various line(s) in that file are referenced objects.  So the existence of a hash ID here retains the objects, even if `origin/next` never got updated (Git versions predating 1.8.2, or one of the other special but unlikely conditions in footnote 1).

---

<sup>2</sup>This description omits *annotated tag* objects.  Those, too, contain hash IDs and cause the target object to be referenced (and traversed if it is a tag, commit, or tree object).  Note that each commit contains the hash ID of one tree object.  The garbage collection code must walk this tree object, which contains yet more object IDs, to mark those objects as referenced, and of course recursively traverse any sub-trees within the tree.  Fortunately trees cannot refer to anything other than tree and blob objects, or the occasional special gitlink, which is a hash ID taken from a submodule, but which is not traversed here.

---

#### About `FETCH_HEAD`

Looking at the `FETCH_HEAD` file—it's plain text, easy to read—you will find something like this:

```
3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f                branch 'master' of [url]
fc54c1af3ec09bab8b8ea09768c2da4069b7f53e        not-for-merge   branch 'maint' of [url]
61856ae69a2ceb241a90e47953e18f218e4d5f2f        not-for-merge   branch 'next' of [url]
fc16284eae5b5a7c4786612ba2c254f3f23b1086        not-for-merge   branch 'pu' of [url]
9125ddae1445fd35a9e52a21f926a2785a2583b8        not-for-merge   branch 'todo' of [url]
```

(the hash IDs and names and so on will vary, of course).  This is from a `git fetch` without any constraints; one constrained specifically to `next`, and intended for merging, would read instead:

```
61856ae69a2ceb241a90e47953e18f218e4d5f2f                branch 'next' of [url]
```

Since the *next* `git fetch` that you run will *overwrite* the `FETCH_HEAD` file, if no remote-tracking name remembers this hash ID, a future `git fetch` could make object `61856a...d5f2f` eligible for garbage collection.  But if you've *merged* that into your own branch, *your* branch name points to a commit that, when following through the commit graph, eventually points to `61856a...d5f2f`, which—by referencing it—protects that commit from the Grim Collector.

(Note that there is an option, `-a` or `--append`, to `git fetch` to tell it to *append* to the `FETCH_HEAD` file.  However, this could mess with the `git merge` that `git pull` runs as there could now be multiple lines *not* marked `not-for-merge`.  So it's rarely a good idea to use `-a` with `git pull`—you really need to know exactly what you are doing here.)